# JQuery UI Tooltip mouse hover delay?

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items:'.tooltip-object',
    tooltipClass:'preview-tip',
    position: { my: "left+15 top", at: "right center" },
    content:function(callback) {
        $.get('/resources/generate_tooltip.php', {
            id:$(this).data("tooltipid")
        }, function(data) {
            callback(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Say I have the above script that shows tooltips when users hover over a tooltip-object link. Right now the tooltip displaying works fine but if a user rapidly moves their mouse over a bunch of links they will all call the /resources/generate_tooltip.php script even if they will never display.

How would I add a delay to the tooltip so that a user has to keep their mouse on the tooltip-object for a set amount of time before the tooltip is generated?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** You can try something like this.instead of alert make your ajax call.

```js
var timeout;var counter=0;
$(function() {
$( ".selector" ).tooltip();
});
$(".selector").hover(function(e){
var $this=this;
if (!timeout) {
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = null;
        $($this).tooltip( "option", "content", "Awesome title!"+(counter++) );
   }, 1000);//delay of 1 second
}},clearIt);
function clearIt() {
if (timeout) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input title="hi" class='selector'>
```

Comment: Yes, ok that makes sense but how would I replace alert("hi") with the script that generates the content of the tooltip and then place that content in the tooltip?

Comment: @user2827048 see the update.It may help you. you can find the documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `content:function(callback) {` , add checking if none of the tooltips is triggered with this:

```
if ($(".your-tooltip-class").length == 0) { 

$.get('/resources/generate_tooltip.php', {
            id:$(this).data("tooltipid")
        }, function(data) {
            callback(data);
        }); 
}
```